# how can I loop this code until being equating to zero?

Tags: python

I need to solve this problem 
I have a parameter call num, this parameter is a number consist of number that has one column or more like 1 or 222 or 33 so on.
for instance, if I typed 39 the number will multiplication as following
3 * 9 to equal to 27 which consists of two columns are 2 and 7
therefore I'll multiplication 2 * 7 to be 14 the end of this process the number will be consist of one column is 4.
when a number will be equal to one column I will edit the num to be 0
I need just to loop this process many and many times until the remaining one column to be equal to zero how can I do so?

this is my function

```
def presistance(num):
    mult = 1
    arr = []
    i = 0

    # check if num > 9
    while True:
        # numbers in array
        if num > 9:
            for n in str(num):
                arr.append(int(n))
            for n in arr:
                mult *= n  
            return mult
        else:
            num = 0
            return num

print(presistance(39))
```

Comment: Write a test for this condition and replace `True` with it.

Comment: In your own words, what does `while True:` mean? Can you  think of something else you could write there, that reflects what you actually want to happen?

Comment: I think you mean "digits", not "columns".

Comment: I thought persistence was actually the number of iterations for a number to become a single digit.  Otherwise, the current function will always return zero for persistence.  What's the point?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel
upon your words,
I think the mistake in (while True) sentence but if this false?
what should I type instead?

Comment: @DarrylG No the result not always zero, it gives me 27 if num is bigger than 9 and gives me zero if less than or equal to 9 but need it to do the loop and every time retrieve the multiplication number

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin--I was saying the value returned by the function after all the looping is always 0.  For instance, with 39 the sequence for num in the loop is 39->27->14->4->0.  So, after the loop is completed 0 is returned. To the outside caller, this is just a function that always returns 0.  I was saying that persistence is not this final value of 0 but how many loops does it take to reach 0.  The number of loops varies with the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning mult you can simply set num equal to mult. Then the code will loop again in the while loop and check the next case and keep going until num only has one digit.

```
while True:
        # numbers in array
        mult = 1
        arr = []
        if num > 9:
            for n in str(num):
                arr.append(int(n))
            for n in arr:
                mult *= n  
            num = mult
            print(num)
        else:
            num = 0
            return num
```

Comment: I get 0 for any number I type into an argument
I want to repeat the loop of this process, for instance: 
27
14
4
0

Comment: The code will always return 0 because it will go through the process of 27 14 4 0 and then set num to 0 and return. I edited my answer to include a print statement that should help you see what is happening at each stage

Comment: I get a weird answer: the result of the process is, 27
10206
0
0
I did debug but I didn't understand why I got this result

Comment: You have to reset the values of mult to 1 and set arr to empty at each iteration of the while loop which I added to my code. I just tested with 39 and I got 27 14 4 0

Comment: ouch, 
my mistake was I add the variables out of the loops and then no looping occurs
Thanks for this hint bro